# Remove whitespace after comma using FPAT Var

Tags: awk

Here's my code

```
 BEGIN {
         FPAT="([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")"
 }
 {
 print "NF = ", NF
 for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
         printf("$%d = <%s>\n", i, $i)}
 }
```

And the output are :

```
NF =  3
$1 = <Johny Bravo>
$2 = < Chief of Security>
$3 = < 417-555-66>
```

There's whitespace before the string. How to remove that whitespace? The whitespace in input are space after ",". The Input from .txt file that contain record like :

```
Johny Bravo, Chief of Security, 417-555-66
```

Expected output

```
NF =  3
$1 = <Johny Bravo>
$2 = <Chief of Security>
$3 = <417-555-66>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

You may call `gsub` inside the `for` loop to remove leading and trailing spaces from each field.

```
s='Johny Bravo, Chief of Security, 417-555-66'

awk -v FPAT='("[^"]+")"|[^,]+' '{
   for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
      gsub(/^ +| +$/, "", $i)
      printf("$%d = <%s>\n", i, $i)
   }
}' <<< "$s"
```

```
$1 = <Johny Bravo>
$2 = <Chief of Security>
$3 = <417-555-66>
```